# Rewrite rule to add .php extension not working in combination with HTTPS redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I hope somebody may be able to help. I want to remove file extensions (.php) from my internal links but of course I need to first configure this in htaccess.

I believe that the correct code is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

however, when I add this code underneath / above the **pre-existing** **code (to force https)**, nothing happens i.e. I still have to enter .php into the URL.

The htaccess file looks like this after adding the above code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any ideas why this wouldn't be working?

Thanks

I’ve been scouring the web but all posts say to simply add the rewrite code to htaccess, which unfortunately isn’t working.

I think the code isn’t playing well with the pre existing code to force https?

Comment: Try by making the last two lines of the .htaccess as the lines after the RewriteEngine On, may be this works.

Comment: As an aside, it's best not to think of rewrite rules as "removing" the file extension, because it can sometimes get you into a muddle about what's possible and how things relate to each other. It's really the other way around - the browser sends the URL *without* the extension, and the rewrite rule *adds it on*.

Comment: @MansoorShiraz, yes I tried this and changing the order around but that didn’t work, sadly. Somebody else suggested adding option -multiviews but I’m pretty sure I already tried that. I just cannot get it to work

Comment: Does the http to https redirect work on its own?

Comment: Yes, @apokryfos the http to https works fine on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I think the RewriteRule is to complex. I use the following for all my websites:

```
# append .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .* $0.php [L]

# fallback to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: does this rule achieve the objective enabling links to not contain .php?

Comment: The first triple is used, if file `XXX` does not exists, but file `XXX.php` exists. The second triple is used, if neither file nor directory exists.